# cluster-autoscaler doesn't scale up the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I create a `k8s` cluster by `kops` on `aws`, the node auto scaling group configuration like:

```
metadata:
creationTimestamp: "2017-03-21T03:53:26Z"
name: nodes
spec:
  associatePublicIp: true
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.4-debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-ebs-2016-10-21
  machineType: t2.medium
  maxSize: 5
  minSize: 2
  role: Node
  zones:
  - us-west-1a
  - us-west-1c
```

the `aws` console shows current asg like:

```
desired:2; min:2; max:5
```

then I install the `add-ons` --- `cluster-autoscaler` by using the [official doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md), then I deploy a pod which current cluster can't supply the resource, but `cluster-autoscaler` doesn't add the node to the cluster, logs is like below:

```
admin@ip-10-0-52-252:/var/log$kubectl logs -f cluster-autoscaler-1581749901-fqbzk -n kube-system
I0322 07:08:43.407683       1 event.go:216] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"new-mq-test-951523717-trd2s", UID:"9437ac54-0ecd-11e7-8779-0257a5d4c012", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"189546", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
I0322 07:08:43.407910       1 event.go:216] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"new-mq-test-951523717-n986l", UID:"9437a3db-0ecd-11e7-8779-0257a5d4c012", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"189543", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
```

so why the `cluster-autoscaler` doesn't scale up the cluster by adding the ec2 nodes ? any answers are very appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally I found the answer, my default `kops` configuration of `nodes` asg is `t2.medium`, while I deploy the pod which require a `5000M` for memory, as we all konw `t2.medium` memory is `4GB` which can't fit the requirement, so the `cluster-autoscaler` can't scale up!

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue while trying to use Kubernetes autoscaling on Google Container Engine. This normally happens when your cluster doesn't contain enough nodes to accomodate anymore Kubernetes **pod**.

The solution to this is to enable autoscaling in your cluster (AWS EC2 in your case) along with kubernetes autoscaling.

Checkout the following Kubernetes documentation for autoscaling on AWS for further information: [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/#scaling-the-cluster).

Comment: I use the `cluster_autoscaler` `add-on` to scale the cluster which means I don't want to change the cluster manually.